# How can I count the number of permutations of some string matching a set of subsets?

Tags: string, algorithm, set, sequence, permutation

I have a string S and a set of subsets of permutations of S, called M.  The elements of M limit the allowed permutations of S.  I want to count the number of allowed permutations of S.  The only restriction on the allowed elements of M is that the subsets contained correspond to the beginning or the ending of some permutation.

For example, say S='ABC' and M = {'AB', 'BC'}.  Thus the only allowed permutations of 'ABC' are 'ABC' and 'CBA'.

I have tried approaching this problem from a number of different directions and can't figure out how to solve it without enumerating all the permutations of S.  Can anyone lend any insight?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how the subsequences limit the permutations? I don't understand why `CBA` is an allowed permutations, it doesn't contain either of the two subsequences as a subsequence.

Comment: that's a subset, not a subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [Inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

In provided example it would be:

`number of permutations that contain "AB" + 
number of permutations that contain "BC" - 
number of permutations that contain both "AB" and "BC"`

You just need to implement a function which counts number of permutations that contain **all** given subsequences.

Notice that if there are subsequences that contain the same letter than:

- You can combine the subsequences, example two subsequences "ABCD" + "CDEF" -> one subsequence "ABCDEF"
- If there is a mismatch than there's no permutation that fits criteria.

Once you've got subsequences with different letters, the result is factorial(length(S) - combined length of all subsequences + number of subsequences).

You can optimize that by memorizing combined subsequences for subsets.

Complexity: 2^|M| * (|S| + |M|).